# What verb? Neither you nor I

Tags: verb-agreement, disjunction

Neither you nor I are going to the show, or, Neither you nor I am going to the show

Comment: The setup itself is the problem.  Neither should mean not one of the following, and one is singular.  Using 'are' covers both 'you' and 'we,' and sounds the best.

Comment: An argument can be made for using either *are* or *am*. In fact, an argument can be made for using *is*. What you need to do is choose a style guide and follow it's preferences  or just choose whichever one sounds best to you. If you are not a native speaker and you don't have an ear attuned to what sounds the most natural, then using a style guide is probably your best bet.

Comment: @Clare, no, *"Neither you nor I am going" is completely unacceptable.  It's a matter of fact, not what some style guide says.

Comment: What "fact" makes *Neither you nor I am...* "completely unacceptable"? What fact makes the other alternatives acceptable? @Greg

Comment: @Clare, the intuitions and usage of native speakers.  English was not created by style guide writers or linguists.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. @Greg

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Controversy over verb choice in "neither you nor I {is/am/are} in control"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122969/controversy-over-verb-choice-in-neither-you-nor-i-is-am-are-in-control)* Also see *[___, ___, and I am/are…](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156634)*, and *[“…as you and I am” versus “…as you and I are”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44171)*, and more tangentially *[What rules make “Remember me, who am your friend” grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662)*

Comment: An ambiguous construction like this is always going to be a friction point for your readers - a place where at least some of them will stop and scratch their heads (and at least a few of them will decide you're wrong, no matter which verb you choose!)  Whenever possible, I try to avoid this sort of awkwardness by rewriting the sentence - in this case, I would go with **"Neither of us _is_ going."**  Of course, this assumes that it's clear who is meant by "us"...

Answer (score 1):

In Garner's *Modern American Usage* (2009), we find the following description:

1 when both subjects are singular, *or* when the second alternative is singular, use a singular verb

2 the verb "precisely"  matches the form of the second verb.

And he adduces the actual real-world usage

> Neither Barton nor I **am** saying that equities aren't a great long-term place to be.

from *Fortune* magazine, 1997.

Thus

> Neither you nor I am going to the show

is the preferred  sentence in formal writing.  See also [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/122981/210913).

I am not telling you what to say. I am saying that when writing a formal paper,   it is best policy to follow a style guide (such as Garner's). If you are not writing a formal paper, you can use other alternatives.

There are other examples in which the verb agrees in form with the closest noun. I'll edit the answer to add these when I have the opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

**[Neither...nor](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-either-or-neither-nor.php)** (from MyEnglishPages.com)

> **When using either/or and neither/nor, note the following rules:**
>
> *1. If both elements are singular, then the verb is singular too.*
>
> *Neither Leila nor Nancy is going to write the report.*
>
> *2. However, if one of the elements is plural, then use a plural verb.*
>
> *Neither the teacher nor the students were in the classroom this morning.*

The pronoun **you** is normally considered as plural. So, **Neither you nor I are going to the show** is the correct sentence.

Comment: "You" is plural only when it refers to more than one individual.  Cf. "You should watch yourself/yourselves." It is not "considered as plural".

Comment: Other than when referring to the word itself (as in @GregLee's comment) and in certain grammatically-incorrect dialects, when would one say _You is_?  While the word **You** may refer to a single person, it sure seems like it is, grammatically, always plural.

Comment: @GregLee, What a great finding! Cite an example sentence in which **you** is used with a singular verb.

Comment: If you simplify the sentence, it becomes obvious:  _You **are** [not] going..._  So despite that the other half -- _I am [not] going..._ -- is singular, the plural part takes precedence.  When you combine them, the plural is used: _Neither You nor I **are** going..._

Comment: Besides, how do you know the _you_ in this case isn't plural?  Adding a little more (hypothetical) context:  _So I told my kids, "neither you nor I **are** going to the show!_  I have three kids so it is most definitely plural.  With such ambiguity, plural wins.

Comment: @mahmudkoya, You appear to have already done so.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn, I don't know -- "you" can be either singular or plural.

Comment: @Grego Lee, Are you happy with that?

Comment: _Cite an example sentence in which "you" is used **as a pronoun** with a singular verb._

Comment: _"you" can be either singular or plural._  Yes, but, because of its ambiguity, "you" as a pronoun always takes the plural form of the verb.  _You [one person] **are** a nice guy._   _You [group of people] **are** all fired._  Except for some local idioms, primarily among people not well-educated, ("_[You is smart, you is kind, you is important](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H50llsHm3k),_") "you" takes the plural form of verbs, even when referring to a single person.  So, yes, "you" can be either singular or plural, but it always needs a plural verb.